# Why doesn't my cascading delete work in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, cascading-deletes

I'm trying to configure cascading deletes in PostgreSQL and created these two tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "public"."User" (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE "public"."Post" (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  title TEXT,
  author INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY (author) REFERENCES "public"."User" (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Now, after having created two related records with

```sql
INSERT INTO "public"."User"("name") VALUES('Alice') RETURNING "id", "name";
INSERT INTO "public"."AnotherPost"("title", "author") VALUES('Hello World', 1) RETURNING "id", "title", "author";
```

I would expect that when deleting a `Post` record, that the respective `User` record is deleted.

```sql
DELETE FROM "public"."Post" WHERE "id"=1;
```

However, the `User` record that I created is still there. Can someone tell me what I'm missing or why this doesn't work?

Comment: The opposite, if you delete a user, its posts are deleted.

Comment: Ah thanks, just figured this out myself as well  if you post this as an answer though I'll accept it so you get your points! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `on delete cascade` foreign key works the opposite way.
I.e. if you delete a user, its posts are also deleted.